# Angular 2 | cannot assign to variable because it is a constant or a read-only property

Tags: angular

When I am using the Variable name in my constructor it is saying the message

> [ts] Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only
>   property !!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer!! We should use this.name.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.name='Amritha';
  }
```